# Is this correct way to render according to the state data using async await?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I got multiple buttons that render different modals.
The modals may render different results according to the data provided in the state.

I got 3 state brackets I need to consider

```
const [cartChangeStoreShow, setCartChangeStoreShow] = useState(false);
const [orderLineId, setOrderLineId] = useState('');
const [storeId, setStoreId] = useState('');
```

`cartChangeStoreShow` is for controlling the visible state of the modal

What I want to do is I wanna change `OrderLineId` and `storeId` before rendering the component.
The data will change according to the orderlineId and storeId.

The component is like this

```
<CartChangeStorePopUp
        visibility={cartChangeStoreShow}
        setCartChangeStoreShow={setCartChangeStoreShow}
        orderLineId={orderLineId}
        storeId={storeId}
/>
```

I am calling api inside `CartChangeStorePopUp` component according to prop data.

So I am handing the user press button like this.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => renderCartChangeStore(cartItem)}>
            <Text>
              Change Store
            </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>


const renderCartChangeStore = async cartItem => {
    try {
      await setOrderLineId(cartItem.orderLineId);
      await setStoreId(cartItem.storeId);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      setCartChangeStoreShow(true);
    }
  };
```

the code is working now but from what I read before

`Async Await` doesn't work properly with `setState`,So I wanna know if there is potential error with the code written here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it does not make sense both the `async/await` presence and the `try/catch/finally`.

`Async/await` is useful when the function you're calling is dealing with something like I/O, time-consuming, where you cannot do anything than "wait" for the completion. Since "to wait" might be something not desirable in a UI context, the `async/await` pattern helps you to keep track to the "slow function", but even leave the CPU free to serve other useful tasks.

That being said, the "setXXX" functions of `React.useState` are not time-consuming: no I/O or similar task involves. Hence, the `async/await` is not applicable.

Going further, the "setXXX" functions of `React.useState` throw no error on setting. They're much like setting a variable like so:

```
var storeId = "";

function setStoreId(value) {
    storeId = value;
}
```

That is, the `try/catch/finally` is quite useless.

If you want, you might optimize the code by grouping the three variables as a single immutable object. However, that's up to your real code.

```
const [storeState, setStoreState] = useState({
    cartChangeStoreShow: false, 
    storeId: "", 
    orderLineId: ""
});

const renderCartChangeStore = cartItem => {
    setStoreState({
        cartChangeStoreShow: true,
        storeId: cartItem.storeId,
        orderLineId: cartItem.orderLineId,
    });
  };
```

Here is a more compact way to achieve the same behavior:

```
const renderCartChangeStore = cartItem => {
    setStoreState({
        cartChangeStoreShow: true,
        ...cartItem,
    });
  };
```

Bear in mind that is very important that you treat the storeState as immutable. That is, never ever change a field of the object, rather create a brand new object with the new field value.

At that point, the component should be called like so:

```
const handleCartChangeStoreShow = value => {
    setStoreState({
        ...storeState,
        cartChangeStoreShow: value,
    });
}

<CartChangeStorePopUp
        visibility={storeState.cartChangeStoreShow}
        setCartChangeStoreShow={handleCartChangeStoreShow}
        orderLineId={storeState.orderLineId}
        storeId={storeState.storeId}
/>
```

Notice the handler to correctly alter the `storeState` object. Worthwhile mention how the new value is set. First, all the current `storeState` is copied to a fresh new object, then the new show value is also copied on the same object. However, since that happens after, it'll have an override-effect.